# Asp.net 4.0 has not been registered

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, windows-8.1

When I try to open my Visual Studio project I get the following error:

> Asp.Net has not been registered on the webserver you need to manually configure your webserver for Asp.net 4.0.

---

**Update:**
Nevermind I fixed it:

I just repaired .Net Framework 4.0 and the issue was resolved.

Comment: This is usually from adding IIS as a feature after you have completed your .NET framework or Visual Studio installs. If you do it first, it seems to be OK on Win 7.

Comment: "I just repaired .Net Framework 4.0" - how?

Comment: I repaired it using the Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135. After reloading my project a couple of times after that the problem went away. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 230):

I also fixed this issue by running

`aspnet_regiis -i`

using the visual studio command line tools as an administrator

Comment: There are three, count 'em, three, command prompts below Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 | Visual Studio Tools, namely:

Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)

Visual Studio x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt (2010)

Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt (2010)

Does it matter which one is used for this command?

Comment: A combination of this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/running-the-command-prompt-from-visual-studio-tools-menu/ and then entering the above worked for me.

Comment: With a new machine, I've got the same problem, but the old fix is not working. The Visual Studio command prompt opens for me at:

C:\Program Files <x86>\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

...and entering "aspnet_regiis -i" results in "'aspnet_regiis -i' is not recognized..."

Is there a specific location from where I should be entering this command?

Comment: I use 2013 nto open a web project and have this problem. And I only Find visual studio command prompt(2010) in my computer,  thius I use it execute `aspnet_regiis -i` and use visual studio 2010 to open project and the error disappear, but another error show, then I use Start Without Debugging then this error disappear, too.

Comment: I am still getting the dialog after running aspnet_regiis -i in both the VS 2010 command window (as administrator) and the same window in VS 2017.

Comment: if you got and unrecognized that means you are in wrong directory, so based on your OS drive use the following fully path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Answer (score 173):

This solved the problem

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i
```

Be sure to run the command prompt **as administrator**

Comment: No need of any reboot or anything - this just works!

Answer (score 44):

For those getting this error in after installing **.NET Framework 4.6** - Read and install [one of these hotfixes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6.aspx) to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm getting this error with opening a VS 2010 project right after I installed VS 2015 RTM, re registering IIS doesn't do anything, still get the error in VS 2010, VS2013 is working fine

Comment: This is a link to the KBs for all versions of VS affected by this, not just VS2012. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6.aspx

Comment: @GladeMellor - Thanks. Updated.

Comment: This issue and the mentioned fixes are also relevant after installing .NET Framework 4.5.3, not just limited to 4.6.

Comment: @ChrisO - 4.5.3 is the same as 4.6.  It was only every called 4.5.3 during pre-release.  It was 4.6. by the time it went to GA.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Visual Studio 2012 on windows 10.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me for Visual Studio 2010 SP 1 on windows 10

Comment: Situation you described for Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web on Windows 7. It solves!

Comment: This fixed my problem.. Thank you

Answer (score 19):

**To resolve 'ASP.NET 4.0 has not been registered.** You need to manually configure your Web server for ASP.NET 4.0 in order for your site to run correctly' error when opening a solution we can:

1  Ensure the IIS feature is turned on with ASP.NET. Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features then click 'Turn Windows Featrues on. Then in the IIS --> WWW servers --> App Dev Features ensure that ASP.NET is checked.

[image]

2  And run the following cmd line to install

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the trick to get it working on Win 8.1 along with making sure that 4.5 s checked.

Comment: This is also applies to W10. http://modelrail.otenko.com/electronics/asp-net-4-5-has-not-been-registered-on-the-web-server Check out this link.

Comment: @teapeng where in my case I selected ASP.NET 4.6

Answer (score 12):

The `aspnet_regiis` approach described above doesn't appear to work on Windows 8.1:

```
C:\Windows\system32>aspnet_regiis -i
```

> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.33440
>   Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.33440).
>   This option is not supported on this version of the operating system. Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog, the Server Manager management tool, or the `dism.exe` command line tool. For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
>   Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.33440).

As indicated in the message, I went to:

1. *Start*
2. *Turn Windows features on or off*
3. *.NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services*

and checked *ASP.NET 4.5*.

This seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: Hmm, When I go to that area "ASP.NET 4.5" is already checked, I unchecked it hit apply and then rechecked it and hit apply but still get that dialog box.

Comment: This fixed my problem on Windows 8.1 - I installed VS2012 Pro after installing 4.5- weird that it did not auto install these services.

Answer (score 10):

Open:

```
Start Menu
-> Programs
-> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
-> Visual Studio Tools
-> Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)
```

Run in command prompt:

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

Make sure it is run at administrator, check that the title starts with `Administrator`:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx - See this on registering IIS for ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: aspnet_regiis is a handy function to know. I use it more than I care to admit.

Answer (score 7):

[Asp.net 4.0 has not been registered](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6/)

Visual Studio 2013
Download Visual Studio 2013 Update 4
For more information on the Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, please refer to: Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 KB Article

Visual Studio 2012
An update to address this issue for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has been published: KB3002339
To install this update directly from the Microsoft Download Center, here

Visual Studio 2010 SP1
An update to address this issue for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 has been published: KB3002340
This update is available from Windows Update
To install this update directly from the Microsoft Download Center, here
http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/E/67E041A1-00DA-4948-90BE-75A0146C08F5/VS10SP1-KB3002340-x86.exe

Comment: Thanks a lot, the fix for VS 2010 SP1 works for me! (fresh install on a W10)

Answer (score 4):

**Go to Visual Studio 2010 Command prompt and set the Directives as :**

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>**

then install IIS by following command:

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i**

now iis will working..
its better if your restart the computer

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but solved it......
Microsoft has a fix for something close to this that actually worked to solve this issue. you can visit this page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6.aspx

The issue occurs after you installed framework 4.5 and/or framework 4.6.
The Visual Studio 2012 Update 5 doesn't fix the issue, I tried that first.

The msdn blog has this to say:
"After the installation of the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6, users may experience the following dialog box displayed in Microsoft Visual Studio when either creating new Web Site or Windows Azure project or when opening existing projects....."

According to the Blog the dialog is benign. just click OK, nothing is effected by the dialog...
The comments in the blog suggests that VS 2015 has the same problem, maybe even worse.

Answer (score 2):

If ASP.NET 4.0 is not registered with IIS

```
*****Use this step if u cant access using run command*****
```

Go to

C Drive 
-->>windows
-->>Microsoft.Net
-->>Framework
-->>v4.0.30319

```
(Choose whatever framework to register with IIS me selecting Framework 4)
```

-->>aspnet_regiis

```
(Double-click or right click & choose run as administrator)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Windows 8.1 which wouldn't support the aspnet_regiis -i approach.

Instead you need to go to Control Panel, locate the "Turn Windows features on or off" option and drill down as follows:

**Internet Information Services**
-> **World Wide Web Services**
-> **Application Development Features**
and check the "**ASP.NET 4.5**" option. In checking this box, other options such as ".NET Extensibility 4.5" and the ISAPI options will be checked automatically.

Apply the changes by clicking OK. Restart your website in IIS and your site should now be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I repaired it using the [**Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135). After reloading my project a couple of times after that the problem went away.