# Asp.net 4.0.768 Has Not Been Registered with WebService + Windows 8.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-8.1

I have VS 2010, a project that need .net 4.0 and window 8.1

When I run the project I get this error

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

Comment: Naw that does not work with windows 8.1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836228/asp-net-4-0-has-not-been-registered See last post...I tried what that guy did but it did not wokr.