# Asp.Net Application was not working when we deployed in IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-8

In Windows Server 2012 created simple Asp.Net using Visual studio 2012. Then I have deployed it in IIS 8.0. In IIS manger browse the deployed simple Asp.Net application, it was working fine when the sample Visual studio project is open. After closing the Visual studio project then we browse it from IIS manager option, the application was not working.

Please provide the solution if you know about it.

Note: The page can't be displayed error be occur.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Please post your answer if you know @TylerH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few Things you need to  check  for hosting in IIS.

1. [**Application Pool frameWork**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836228/asp-net-4-0-has-not-been-registered) : Ensure the correct framwork is installed V(4.0.30319).

   Navigate to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` directory

   Open command window here (CTRL + SHIFT + rightClick)

   Type in the Command prompt  `aspnet_regiis -i` to  register the latest framework.
2. **Physical path Security/permission** :
   IIS -> (select your VD) -> Manage Application-> Advanced settings -> Physical path credential -> Choose connect as Specific user -> provide the systems username and password.
3. Add read/write permission for IIS_IUSERS object