# How to configure Normal html page in IIS?

Tags: html, iis

I have created two normal HTML pages website and want to configure and access through IIS.

I did the following things. 
 1. Added new website in IIS. 
 2. Specified physical path of folder(Website).

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any error message ? what is going wrong ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand yes i have "The requested URL can not be retrieved" this error

Comment: You need to give Permission to the Physical path of the html File or you can put your folder inside C://inetpub/wwwroot/

Comment: Also you can follow few configuration changes  in IIS
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813516/asp-net-application-was-not-working-when-we-deployed-in-iis-8-0/29813712#29813712