# IIS 8 shows a blank page with no errors instead of .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

This is frustrating me to no end. I've upgraded a project from .NET 2 to .NET 4.5 and I'm having difficulties launching the new site.

If I leave my .aspx page as it was - nothing loads. I get a "Failed to load response data" when I try to investigate the only item that loads in my "Network" tab (dev console). The item that loads (doesn't load, really) is /WA, the name of my project set up in IIS.

Now, if I change the default document to be a .html page, it renders some garbage and at least shows things. (Literally change the extension to .html from .aspx).

My project runs fine locally on the same server using Visual Studio. It does not work when using IIS. It is using the DefaultAppPool with .Net CLR Version 4.0 - Pipeline mode: Classic.

Googling of other solutions to this seem to point to HTTP Errors and Static Content needing to be set to on, yet they are already installed in my "Turn windows Features On/Off"...

Answer (score 0):

can you try this because seems like asp.net is not well registered: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880184/271637)

Comment: I did try this. I get a message saying "This option is not supported on this version of the operating system. Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog, the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.

----- And I have done this using Turn Windows Features On/Off. ASP.NET 4.5 is installed under Web Server (ISS) / Web Server / Application Development.