# ASP.NET 4.0 has not been registered on web server error

Tags: asp.net

I have installed visual studio 2012 and my .net framework is 4.5 and in that when i am creating web site project i am getting following error.
[image]

Please suggest me what I have to do.

Comment: duplicate? :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836228/asp-net-4-0-has-not-been-registered]

Comment: Repair your visual studio, and check everything is installed correctly or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed `dot net 4.0` then go to `Application pool` on `IIS` and change it to `dotNet 4.0`. Run this command on CMD too: `aspnet_regiis -i`