# Configure ASP.NET with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am using visual studio 2012. When I open asp.net web form application the following message is showing Everytime:

Configuring web **http://"localhost":54229/ for ASP.NET 4.0 failed**.You must manually configure this site for ASP.NET 4.0 in order for the site to run correctly. ASP.NET 4.0 has not been registered on the Web server. You need to manually configure your Web server for ASP.NET 4.0 in order for you site to run correctly.
How to get free of this message?

Comment: Do you have <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" /> in web.config file?

Comment: Check: [Asp.net 4.0 has not been registered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5836228/1351076)

Comment: thanks,  now it is working correctly

Comment: @Ramzan
How did you make it work? Using the repair tool or manually by adding the HTTP line.

Answer (score 1):

Just to satisfy my OCD and give an answer, the link provided by @krlzlx does indeed solve the problem.  According to the [current] top voted answer of [Asp.net 4.0 has not been registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836228/asp-net-4-0-has-not-been-registered), run

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

as admin from the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio.